# Is there a way to deny the global administrator access to a specific folder/library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, access-denied

I need to find a way to deny specific users who are global administrators access to a specific library on our SharePoint site.

Human Resources wants to create a library that only a select group of people can see and open/read any documents or files. I was hoping to create an AD Style group which would deny their access but everything I read says that SharePoint does not have that capability. I would appreciate any assistance possible to get his resolved quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As said, you can not deny the Global admin to access the documents. But what you can do is put the control in place.

We have auditing enabled on the sites / Document libraries which give us the report who view or edit or delete the documents. Check this "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2"

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no Deny type right. And even if there was, a Global Admin could override such a right.

This is more of an HR issue (trust) than a technical issue.